# assigning parameters to one variable c++

Tags: c++

Our project is to make a search engine for events with any DS we want.the search engine will have the date of the event, and a description of the event. Our group chose to make it using hashing and if there is any collision we solve it by inserting it in a BST. The problem is when i insert the values DATE and DESCRIPTION, i want to make the value of the node both the date, and the desc. so i wrote this, but obviously it won't work. Do you know how can i pass the value of the parameters to one variable (the node)??

```
void insert2(int date, string desc){
    ..........
    newNode->setVal(date + desc); //Problem
    .........}
```

Comment: How does a node in your tree look like?

Comment: Besides the fact that you're trying to add a string to an int, I didn't really understand your problem. Please note that C++ != PHP. Please describe the issue clearly and post a [SSCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: The answer more or less depends on what parameter `setVal` takes. (Or is that part of the question too?)

Comment: He's a beginner, is not wrong for him to ask about this. I'm currently teaching programming and questions like this are very common during the first classes and I don't see a reason for downvoting it. Also this is obviously caused because of programming teachers not really teaching programming but only teaching how to call program code which is already written.

Comment: @hellfire The title *clearly* says C++, and one of the parameters is `string`, which does not exist in C. Please do not add [c] tags to C++ questions.

Comment: @Cody Gray using string doesn't say that it is std::string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you want to combine date and description into a single object.

A.
You can create a structure or class to combine your data.
http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/structures/

```
struct SearchEngineEntry{
    int date;
    string desc;
};


void insert2(int date, string desc){
    //...
    SearchEngineEntry entry;
    entry.date = date;
    entry.desc = desc;
    newNode->setVal(SearchEngineEntry{entry); //Problem
    //...    
}
```

B. You can use a build in data structure
    http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/tuple/tuple/

```
void insert2(int date, string desc){
    //...
    std::tuple<int,string> entry(date,desc);
    newNode->setVal(entry); //Problem
    //...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A third solution would be to convert the int to a string for concatenation.

```
newNode->setVal(std::to_string(date) + desc);
```

You could also change the node implementation to accept two values.

```
Node::setVal(int date, std::string desc) { //...
```

But without knowing the rest of your code it's hard to give a specific answer.